# Can we create context managers in Go like how we have in python

Tags: go

In python, I find the context managers really helpful. I was trying to find the same in *Go*.

e.g:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    do something here
```

where open is a context manager in python handling the entry and exit, which implicitly takes care of closing the file opened.

Instead of we explicitly doing like this:

```
f := os.Open("filename")
//do something here
defer f.Close()
```

Can this be done in Go as well ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/p1fckg/context-managers-in-go-don-t-be-ridiculous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't, but you can create the same illusion with a little wrapper func:

```
func WithFile(fname string, fn func(f *os.File) error) error {
    f, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    return fn(f)
}
```

Comment: Actually i was not just looking for opening and closing of a file. Just provided that as an example. Looking for more or less like `__enter__` and `__exit__`, which we have in python.

Comment: @Chinmay the answer is still no, there's [`runtime.SetFinalizer`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) but it shouldn't really be relayed on since it's not always guaranteed to run.

Comment: Thanks, marking it as the answer, May be you can provide the usage of the method `WithFile` to make it complete.

Comment: It exists in a less convenient form with a different syntax than Python. You can [see an inline example on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yv9VlnmwDU) that is usable in many situations rather than using a specific function for `*os.File` objects. That said, this answer isn't wrong, just specific to `*os.File` since that was the context of the original question. Basically, the only difference between Go and Python is that you must call the `Close` method of the file explicitly, even if you `defer` the call until the function exits.